# When installing ubuntu to a USB drive, I keep getting a "No such file or directory" error

Tags: usb, downloads

So this is the error I keep getting. I have already unmounted the disk and currently have ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso on my desktop. Thank you for the help.

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuHl1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have literally typed `/path/to/` as part of your command? Do directories of that name exist on your system? You are meant to replace those words with the actual location of the file...